# (Angular 6) Let Item of Itens from database

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to bring up a list from a database. The process of *ngFor is mostly simple, but i never tried to make it using data from an external font. 
The first thing i'm doing is calling a get() method, which brings me all the data from my source, the process works like this:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.get().subscribe(x => { 
    this.User = x; 
    console.log(this.User[0]);
    console.log(this.User[1]);
    console.log(this.User[2]);
  }); 

}
```

The logs are bringing me all the info correctly, just like it is in the db, so up to this moment, everything is fine.
This is what the log shows me:

> { 
>   camp: 1 
>   campAt: true 
>   campRep: true 
>   code: 102 
>   date: null 
>   name: "John Test" 
>   sig: "ZCD" 
>   stat: 0 
>   } 
>   ...........

Now, when making the *ngFor, i'm not being able to pull the 'name' property of the User, this is how i'm doing it:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let User of Users">
        <span>{{User}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I have also tried something like

> User.name

or

> User[] | User[].name | User[i]

Really, I have no idea how to bring the data from User to the *ngFor... 
So, what's the trick here?

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is in name of variable.

```
this.get().subscribe(x => { 
   this.User = x;    // You are using 'User'
});
```

And in `HTML` you are using `Users`

```
<ul>
   <li *ngFor="let data of User">
      <span>{{data.name}}</span>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting `x` in `User` not `Users`.

`this.User = x`

Change that to `this.Users`, so you can traverse `Users`